# Wordpress Pagination 404 error on page 2 with custom post type

Tags: wordpress

In my Wordpress custom theme, a pagination giving the 404 error when loading the page above 1. I have checked out the Permalinks and other stuff but no success.

code.

```
//Loop
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

                 $args = array(
                     'orderby' => 'date',
                     'post_type' => 'jobs',
                     'posts_per_page' => 1,
                     'paged' => 'paged'
                 );
                 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

//Pagination
$total = $the_query->max_num_pages;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
if( $total > 1 )  {
 if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
     $current_page = 1;
 if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
     $format = 'page/%#%/';
 } else {
     $format = '&paged=%#%';
 }
 echo paginate_links(array(
     'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
     'format'        => $format,
     'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
     'total'         => $total,
     'mid_size'      => 3,
 ) );
}
```